# Apply a function to result of a function

Tags: smarty

In my tpl file i have this part of code that displays a string:

`{l s='blabla' mod='module'}`

I would like to apply the `html_entity_decode` function to this string before it will be displayed.

How to deal with this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{capture assign="foobar"}{l s='blabla' mod='module'}{/capture}
{$foobar|unescape:"htmlall"}
```

I'm not sure if the modifier unescape was available in Smarty2. It is since (at least) Smarty3.1